# How to prevent the Facebook app (Android) to auto refresh/update the newsfeed?

Tags: facebook

I have a lot of news(paper) articles in my Facebook news feed and so I often open up the linked article to read it in the browser.
After that I want to go back to the Facebook app to read the comments on this post which linked to the article, but at this moment is the app refreshing the news feed and the post disappears.

If I read the article fast enough, then I can go back to the post without a refresh.
I did not measure the time frame in which I have to go back, but it feels like a minute or so and it often takes much longer to read the articles.

Some time agao was there an option to adjust the refreshing time, but it looks as if this option is not available anymore.

How can I prevent the auto-refresh in general in the app (I actually know by my self when I want to do a refresh or not), or how can I adjust at least the refreshing time frame?

Answer (score 0):

Close your Facebook app,
Go to your settings, under manage apps, select Facebook. Then clear cache.

Thereafter logout of your Facebook account, then log in again.

That has resolved the issue to an extent here.